# Integrating Java Web Application with Tally software

Tags: java, oracle

I have a java web application using oracle 10g as database server .The datas are inserted using my web application in the tables. Is it possible to configure Tally Software to use the data in those tables?? Please Guide !!!

Comment: What dates? How Tally should use them?

Comment: I populate accounting information in a table through my web application .
I want Tally to use this information to generate ledger . is it possible ???